How does Python's Binascii.a2b_base64 (base64.b64decode) work?
I checked the source code in Python and implemented a function that is the same as the Python's binascii.a2b_base64 function.
This function is located under path Python-3.12.4/Modules/binascii.c, line 387.
static PyObject *
binascii_a2b_base64_impl(PyObject *module, Py_buffer *data, int strict_mode)

I used C++ and re implemented this function in my own code according to the original function in Python, in order to better understand and learn the working principle of Base64 decoding.
However, I don't know why the function I implemented cannot handle non Base64 encoded characters correctly.
I have checked these codes and confirmed that they do not affect the function's handling of non Base64 encoded characters, such as function [_PyBytesWriter_Init, _PyBytesWriter_Alloc, _PyBytesWriter_Finish, ...], and ignored it from my code.
When processing Base64 strings that comply with the RFC4648 standard, as well as, In the case where only \n is used as a non Base64 encoded character, the function I implemented will achieve the same result as the corresponding function in Python.
For example:
const char *encoded = {
    "QUJDREVGR0hJSktMTU5PUFFSU1RVVldYWVpBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVW\n"
    "V1hZWkFCQ0RFRkdISUpLTE1OT1BRUlNUVVZXWFlaQUJDREVGR0hJSktMTU5PUFFS\n"
    "U1RVVldYWVpBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWg==\n"
};

Using either my function or Python's binascii.a2b_base64 function will yield the same result as the following:
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Here is the specific implementation of my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdexcept>

#define BASE64PAD '='

constexpr uint8_t b64de_table[256] = {
    255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255, 62, 255,255,255, 63,
    52 , 53, 54, 55,  56, 57, 58, 59,  60, 61,255,255, 255,  0,255,255,

    255,  0,  1,  2,   3,  4,  5,  6,   7,  8,  9, 10,  11, 12, 13, 14,
    15 , 16, 17, 18,  19, 20, 21, 22,  23, 24, 25,255, 255,255,255,255,
    255, 26, 27, 28,  29, 30, 31, 32,  33, 34, 35, 36,  37, 38, 39, 40,
    41 , 42, 43, 44,  45, 46, 47, 48,  49, 50, 51,255, 255,255,255,255,

    255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255,

    255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255};

uint8_t *
pyBase64Decode(const char *buffer, size_t &length,
               bool strict_mode = false)
{
    std::string error_message;

    const uint8_t *ascii_data = (const uint8_t *)buffer;
    size_t ascii_len = length;
    bool padding_started = 0;

    size_t bin_len = ascii_len / 4 * 3; 
    uint8_t *bin_data = new (std::nothrow) uint8_t[bin_len + 1];
    if(!bin_data) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to allocate memory for bin_data.");
    }
    uint8_t *bin_data_start = bin_data;
    bin_data[bin_len] = 0x0;

    uint8_t leftchar = 0;
    uint32_t quad_pos = 0;
    uint32_t pads = 0;

    if(strict_mode && (ascii_len > 0) && (*ascii_data == BASE64PAD)) {
        error_message = "Leading padding not allowed.";
        goto error_end;
    }

    size_t i;
    uint8_t this_ch;
    for(i = 0; i < ascii_len; ++i) {
        this_ch = ascii_data[i];

        if(this_ch == BASE64PAD) {
            padding_started = true;
            // If the current character is a padding character, the length
            // will be reduced by one to obtain the decoded true length.
            bin_len--;

            if(strict_mode && (!quad_pos)) {
                error_message = "Excess padding not allowed.";
                goto error_end;
            }

            if((quad_pos >= 2) && (quad_pos + (++pads) >= 4)) {

                if(strict_mode && ((i + 1) < ascii_len)) {
                    error_message = "Excess data after padding.";
                    goto error_end;
                }

                goto done;
            }

            continue;
        }

        this_ch = b64de_table[this_ch];
        if(this_ch == 255) {
            if(strict_mode) {
                error_message = "Only base64 data is allowed.";
                goto error_end;
            }
            continue;
        }

        if(strict_mode && padding_started) {
            error_message = "Discontinuous padding not allowed.";
            goto error_end;
        }

        pads = 0;

        switch(quad_pos) {
        case 0:
            quad_pos = 1;
            leftchar = this_ch;
            break;
        case 1:
            quad_pos = 2;
            *bin_data++ = (leftchar << 2) | (this_ch >> 4);
            leftchar = this_ch & 0xf;
            break;
        case 2:
            quad_pos = 3;
            *bin_data++ = (leftchar << 4) | (this_ch >> 2);
            leftchar = this_ch & 0x3;
            break;
        case 3:
            quad_pos = 0;
            *bin_data++ = (leftchar << 6) | (this_ch);
            leftchar = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(quad_pos) {
        if(quad_pos == 1) {
            char tmpMsg[128]{};
            snprintf(tmpMsg, sizeof(tmpMsg),
                    "Invalid base64-encoded string: "
                    "number of data characters (%zd) cannot be 1 more "
                    "than a multiple of 4",
                    (bin_data - bin_data_start) / 3 * 4 + 1);
            error_message = tmpMsg;
            goto error_end;
        } else {
            error_message = "Incorrect padding.";
            goto error_end;
        }
        error_end:
        delete[] bin_data;
        throw std::runtime_error(error_message);
    }

done:
    length = bin_len;
    return bin_data_start;
}

How to use this function:
int main()
{
    const char *encoded = "aGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkLg==";
    size_t length = strlen(encoded);
    uint8_t *decoded = pyBase64Decode(encoded, length);
    printf("decoded: %s\n", decoded);
    return 0;
}


Here are a few samples with different results after executing Python and my code.
original decoded:
stackoverflow

original encoded:
c3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdw==

sample 1:



original
"c3##RhY2t...vdmV!?y~Zmxvdw=="




result of python
"stackoverflow"


result of pyBase64Decode
"stackoverflowP"[^print_method_1]


result of pyBase64Decode
"stackoverflow"[^print_method_2] but, length: 19



sample 2:



original
"c3\n\nRh~Y2tvd#$mVyZmx$vdw=="




result of python
"stackoverflow"


result of pyBase64Decode
"stackoverflow"[^print_method_1] but, length: 16



sample 3:



original
"c3Rh$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$Y2tvdmVy###############Zmxvdw=="




result of python
"stackoverflow"


result of pyBase64Decode
"stackoverflowP\2;SP2;SPROFILE_"[^print_method_1] length: 40 Bytes


result of pyBase64Decode
"stackoverflow"[^print_method_2] but, length: 40




[^print_method_1]: cout << std::string((char *)decoded, length) << endl;
[^print_method_2]: printf("%s", decoded);

What is BASE64PAD

@trincot I have corrected the omission in the question.

Please add relevant #include. Guessing them is no fun. | The allocatin is different https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/binascii.c . You allocate different amount of memory and place zero byte in the string before parsing =. The presented output suggests that you did not place a zero terminating characters in the output, but I do not undestand it. Please post the full code with "print method 1" and "print method 2" into the question, please add environment, operating system, compiler version and options use. Check code with gcc -fanalyzer, sanitizers and using valgrind.

I didn't check the source code of the Python implementation, but the issue in your C++ implementation is in the if(this_ch == 255) block:
In this case the length of the output will be impacted, as you had based bin_len on ascii_len, where the latter included these non-base64 characters. But as they have no bearing to the output, bin_len will need to be adapted.
I would suggest to fix this as follows:

Keep track of the number of characters that have no data representation, including = and non-base64 characters. You could use a variable skip for that, initialised at 0.

At the very end, in the done section, recalculate bin_len with that information, and only then place the \0 terminator in bin_data.


Here is your code with just those modifications. Comments indicate where the changes occur:
uint8_t *
pyBase64Decode(const char *buffer, size_t &length,
               bool strict_mode = false)
{
    size_t skip = 0; // Add this variable
    std::string error_message;

    const uint8_t *ascii_data = (const uint8_t *)buffer;
    size_t ascii_len = length;
    bool padding_started = 0;

    size_t bin_len = ascii_len / 4 * 3; 
    uint8_t *bin_data = new (std::nothrow) uint8_t[bin_len + 1];
    if(!bin_data) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to allocate memory for bin_data.");
    }
    uint8_t *bin_data_start = bin_data;
    bin_data[bin_len] = 0x0; // This could be omitted, as we will do it in "done".

    uint8_t leftchar = 0;
    uint32_t quad_pos = 0;
    uint32_t pads = 0;

    if(strict_mode && (ascii_len > 0) && (*ascii_data == BASE64PAD)) {
        error_message = "Leading padding not allowed.";
        goto error_end;
    }

    size_t i;
    uint8_t this_ch;
    for(i = 0; i < ascii_len; ++i) {
        this_ch = ascii_data[i];

        if(this_ch == BASE64PAD) {
            padding_started = true;
            skip++; // Instead of decreasing bin_len, increase the new variable
            if(strict_mode && (!quad_pos)) {
                error_message = "Excess padding not allowed.";
                goto error_end;
            }
            if((quad_pos >= 2) && (quad_pos + (++pads) >= 4)) {
                if(strict_mode && ((i + 1) < ascii_len)) {
                    error_message = "Excess data after padding.";
                    goto error_end;
                }
                goto done;
            }
            continue;
        }
        this_ch = b64de_table[this_ch];
        if(this_ch == 255) {
            if(strict_mode) {
                error_message = "Only base64 data is allowed.";
                goto error_end;
            }
            skip++;
            continue;
        }
        if(strict_mode && padding_started) {
            error_message = "Discontinuous padding not allowed.";
            goto error_end;
        }
        pads = 0;
        switch(quad_pos) {
        case 0:
            quad_pos = 1;
            leftchar = this_ch;
            break;
        case 1:
            quad_pos = 2;
            *bin_data++ = (leftchar << 2) | (this_ch >> 4);
            leftchar = this_ch & 0xf;
            break;
        case 2:
            quad_pos = 3;
            *bin_data++ = (leftchar << 4) | (this_ch >> 2);
            leftchar = this_ch & 0x3;
            break;
        case 3:
            quad_pos = 0;
            *bin_data++ = (leftchar << 6) | (this_ch);
            leftchar = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(quad_pos) {
        if(quad_pos == 1) {
            char tmpMsg[128]{};
            snprintf(tmpMsg, sizeof(tmpMsg),
                    "Invalid base64-encoded string: "
                    "number of data characters (%zd) cannot be 1 more "
                    "than a multiple of 4",
                    (bin_data - bin_data_start) / 3 * 4 + 1);
            error_message = tmpMsg;
            goto error_end;
        } else {
            error_message = "Incorrect padding.";
            goto error_end;
        }
        error_end:
        delete[] bin_data;
        throw std::runtime_error(error_message);
    }

done:
    bin_len = (ascii_len - skip) * 3 / 4;  // Recalculate
    length = bin_len;
    bin_data[bin_len] = 0x0; // ...and place the terminator only now
    return bin_data_start;
}


Although it is not a perfect solution (as there is still a problem), I still adopted this solution because even though I asked questions in the Python community, I did not get a better solution. This stems from Python having its own memory management approach.

Could you provide an example that illustrates the problem you spotted?

Sorry, I didn't make it clear before. The message I left under your answer is not specific to the current topic. The issue with the current topic has been resolved. However, neither your code nor the code I wrote before took into account the issue of memory space (during uint8_t *bin_data = new (std::nothrow) uint8_t[bin_len + 1];, I applied for a larger space than actually occupied, If it is a contaminated base64 encoding string.).

But that is not really a problem, is it? Either you reallocate memory to copy the used data and then free the larger memory block, or you first perform a separate loop to calculate the memory needed, and only then do the real work.

yes, I have also come up with many solutions (for performance issues caused by memory and potential memory replication) (because I pursue performance too much, I like to optimize code to the extreme), but now I think about it, performance can be optimized slowly in the future. Now I will continue to complete my other functions.

Another solution, however, is the same drawback as Trincot's proposed solution, which is that the memory usage size of bin_data exceeds the actual usage size.
https://discuss.python.org/t/how-does-pythons-binascii-a2b-base64-base64-b64decode-work/56401/
done:
    length = bin_data - bin_data_start;
    return bin_data_start;
}


Let's see if I have a better solution in a few months.
